# The 'this' context of type '...' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '...'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm creating the type definitions (.d.ts) for a JavaScript library. One of the methods of this library recieves a object of functions, then internally uses the `Function.prototype.bind` in each one of them and expose the modified functions in another context. The new `this` have it's type well defined, but when I try to call the modified functions, I get the following error:

> Both the error messages and the code below are from a simpler reproduction of the original error.

```
index.ts:37:5 - error TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'Callbacks' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'This'.
  Type 'Callbacks' is missing the following properties from type 'This': name, context, number
```

```js
type Fn = (this: This, ...args: any[]) => any | Promise<any>;

interface This {
    name: string;
    context: any;
    number: number;
}

interface Callbacks {
    [key: string]: Fn;
}

const callbacks: Callbacks = {
    multipleNames() {
        return new Array(this.number).fill(this.name).join('\n');
    }
};

function bindCallbacks(): Callbacks {
    const r: Callbacks = {};
    const theThis: This = {
        name: 'John1',
        context: {},
        number: 0
    }

    for (const key in callbacks) {
        const fn = callbacks[key].bind(theThis);
        r[key] = fn;
    }

    return r;
}

function test() {
    const callbacks = bindCallbacks();
    callbacks.multipleNames();
}

test();
```

I can't make the Fn type have an `any` type because I will lose the IntelliSense when creating the original functions, and trying to add an `any` type on `this` on the modified functions won't work either.

Comment: `r`, the return value of `bindCallbacks`, does not have the type `Callbacks` - its properties are bound functions, not `Fn` ones that require being called on a `This`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, it was the problem! I made a new interface for the bound functions without the `this` declaration and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

when you are declaring `callbacks` constant, you are declaring a function called `multipleNames` with no arguments. but in `Fn` type you declared the following:

```js
type Fn = (this: This, ...args: any[]) => any | Promise<any>;
```

so you are forcing your functions to have an argument of type of `This`, witch you have not provided for `multipleNames` function.

you can declare your type as the following so you won't get error you mentioned:

```js
type Fn = (this?: This, ...args?: any[]) => any | Promise<any>;
```

making `this` and `args`, optional arguments

Comment: The argument `this` is not an usual parameter, it the [fake this argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function), so being optional does not solve my problem, as it will remove the intellisense for the parameters. And, with this specific parameter, putting the optional flag will raise another error: `ts(1005)`.